# Outlook AddIn setting data through Setup project

Tags: setup-project, outlook-addin

I have a question regarding to a project I'm actually working on:

I'm doing an Outlook AddIn, and as you know, when you create a new project of this type, visual studio creates for you the Setup project too.

I would like to customize my setup project to ask the user for his username and password (because the addin will connect to an external system to get some data) and send that data to my Outlook AddIn project to make the login when required. The important thing is that I would like to ask for that info only once at the installation steps, because that won't change after the installation. Is it possible to get this behaviour? Cause far as I know, you don't have an app.config or settings.config on an Outlook AddIn type project?.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if you can achieve but you can have a config file in your application which contains a flag. So  when you start outlook for the first time after installing your add in , it will ask for the userId/Password. After getting the informatin, store it and you set the flag in config file. next time during startup,  when you check flag, it is already set, so don't ask for userid/pwd.